# Reading lines from a binary file C++

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to read a binary file and store it into a database, however I get a segmentation fault when I try to store a string type into the database. To be exact, the error occurs inside the push function:

```
new_node->name = name;
```

I can't seem to find a good solution on the web, and I'm aimlessly trying different things... any help would be appreciated.

```
// 
// loadbin.cpp
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#include "studentsDB.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    string name;
    string id;
    int numCourses;
    int crn;
    vector<int> crns;

    studentsDB sDB;
    studentsDB::node *students = 0;

    int in = 1;

    if( argc > 1 ) {

        ifstream infile(argv[in], ios::binary );

        while( !infile.eof() ) {
            infile.read( ( char* )(name.c_str()), sizeof( string ) );
            infile.read( ( char* )(id.c_str()), sizeof( string ) );
            infile.read( ( char* ) &numCourses, sizeof( int ) );

            do{
                crns.push_back( crn );
            }
            while( infile.read( ( char* ) &crn, sizeof( int ) ) );

            sDB.push( &students, (string)name, (string)id, numCourses, crns );
        }
        //sDB.printList( students );
    }


    else
        cout << "Not enough argument" << endl;
}
```

```
void studentsDB::push( struct node** head_ref, string name, string id,
                       int numCourses, vector<int>crns ) {

    struct node* new_node = ( struct node* ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->name = name;
    //new_node->id   = id;
    new_node->numCourses = numCourses;
    //new_node->crns = crns;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);    
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
    size++;
}
```

Comment: Just to nitpick, but in binary files there are no _lines_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is bad:

```
        infile.read( ( char* )(name.c_str()), sizeof( string ) );
```

You can't write to the buffer returned by `c_str()`, it is not guaranteed to be long enough to hold your result.  `sizeof(string)` has nothing to do with the size the string can hold, by the way.  You will need to allocate your own `char[]` buffer to hold the results of `infile.read`, then convert to a `string` afterwards.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I have to somehow know the size of the string or char*? Is there anyway to do that? Also say if I do             infile.read( name,  100  ); and have char name[100], does that mean I would read in the next 100 characters? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need some indication of how long the strings are, and it all depends on how the strings were stored in the first place.  Are they null-terminated?  Newline terminated?  Fixed length?

Comment: name is terminated by a colon, and crns - which can range from 1 - 3 are newline terminated

Comment: What's a crns?  Sounds like you'll have to read the input one character at a time and break when you detect the terminator.

Comment: they are integers that come in 1 - 3 sets. But how would I detect a regular character when reading a binary file?

Comment: binary files are just a sequence of characters.  `char buf[1]; infile.read(buf, 1); if (buf[0] == ':') { ... };`, and so on.